# Tkinter: Simultaneously-scrolling text boxes eventually lose alignment

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement a simple HEX Viewer by using three `Text()` boxes which are set to scroll simultaneously.

However, it seems as though there's some kind of "drift" and at some point, the first box loses alignment with the other two. I can't seem to figure out why.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os

def chunker(seq, size: int):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

TAG_JUSTIFY_RIGHT = 'justify_right'

class Application(tk.Frame):
    BYTES_PER_ROW = 16

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
         
        self.textbox_address = tk.Text(self, width = 17, padx = 10, wrap = tk.NONE, bd = 0)
        self.textbox_address.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y, expand = False)

        self.textbox_address.tag_configure(TAG_JUSTIFY_RIGHT, justify = tk.RIGHT)

        self.textbox_hex = tk.Text(self, width = 47, padx = 10, wrap = tk.NONE, bd = 0)
        self.textbox_hex.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.Y, expand = False)

        self.textbox_ascii = tk.Text(self, width = 17, padx = 10, wrap = tk.NONE, bd = 0)
        self.textbox_ascii.pack(side = tk.LEFT, fill = tk.Y, expand = False)

        self.textboxes = [self.textbox_address, self.textbox_hex, self.textbox_ascii]

        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y, expand = False)

        self.scrollbar['command'] = self._on_scrollbar
        for textbox in self.textboxes:
            textbox['yscrollcommand'] = self._on_textscroll

        self.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True, side = tk.RIGHT)
     
    def _on_scrollbar(self, *args) -> None:
        for textbox in self.textboxes:
            textbox.yview(*args)

    def _on_textscroll(self, *args) -> None:
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)
        self._on_scrollbar('moveto', args[0])

    def _populate_address_area(self, num_bytes: int) -> None:
        num_lines = num_bytes // self.BYTES_PER_ROW
        chars_per_byte = 2
        format_pad_len = 8 * chars_per_byte

        for i in range(num_lines + 1):
            base_address = format(i * self.BYTES_PER_ROW, 'X').rjust(format_pad_len, '0')
            self.textbox_address.insert(tk.END, f"{base_address}\n")

        self.textbox_address.tag_add(TAG_JUSTIFY_RIGHT, 1.0, tk.END)
        self.textbox_address.config(state = tk.DISABLED)

    def populate_hex_view(self, byte_arr: bytes) -> None:
        self._populate_address_area(len(byte_arr))
        
        for chunk in chunker(byte_arr, self.BYTES_PER_ROW):
            hex_format = chunk.hex(" ")
            self.textbox_hex.insert(tk.END, f"{hex_format}\n")

            ascii_format = "".join([chr(i) if 32 <= i <= 127 else "." for i in chunk])
            self.textbox_ascii.insert(tk.END, f"{ascii_format}\n")

        self.textbox_hex.config(state = tk.DISABLED)
        self.textbox_ascii.config(state = tk.DISABLED)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Hex View')
    app = Application(parent = root)
    app.populate_hex_view(bytearray(os.urandom(0x4000)))
    root.mainloop()
```

At first, everything is aligned correctly:

[image]

However, after a while, there's a visible misalignment between the first column and the other two:

[image]

At first I thought that this might be related to line heights, but setting `spacing1`, `spacing2`, and `spacing3` didn't help. The problem also persists if I replace all non-whitespace characters with a single character such as 'O' (to make sure all characters have the same height).

How can I ensure that all three boxes stay aligned?

Comment: I did some testing, and `textbox_address` has `1026` lines, whereas both `textbox_ascii` and `textbox.hex` have `1025` lines. I will let you know if I figure out _why_ this is happening, but there's the _cause_ of your problem, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `_populate_address_area`, there is a `for` loop: `for i in range(num_lines + 1):`. This is the cause of the problem. Using `num_lines + 1` adds one too many linse to `textbox_address`. To fix this, there are two options: deleting the `+ 1`, or using `for i in range(1, num_lines + 1):`. Either way, `textbox_address` will have the correct number of lines.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was so simple. For completeness I'll add that I had to adjust `num_lines` so that it *does* contain an extra line in case `num_bytes` isn't a multiple of `BYTES_PER_ROW`.